# Real-time Linux (RTOS) for beagle bone

Tags: linux, ubuntu, real-time, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am looking for a way to tailor a version of Ubuntu into a real-time OS, and then install it on Beagle Bone Black. I don't know where to start from.

1. What are the typical features one would look for in a real-time version of Ubuntu installed on a Beagle Bone Black?
2. If I want to start changing Beagle Bone's linux into a real-time version and building it, what is the exact procedure? Is there any guide for this?
3. How do I build and install this changed version of linux on Beagle Bone?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: @jww Thank you very much for your comment. However, it is not that I am asking three separate questions. It is one question, and that is it: I am looking for a manual, website, instruction or anything, that can cover the problem of tailoring and installing an RTOS (preferably linux) on Beagle Bone Black.

Answer (score 3):

Linux in itself is not real-time capable ("real-time tasks" = tasks which have a fixed, predictable timing behaviour).  However, there is a so called real-time-patch for Linux called "PREEMPT_RT" which addresses the most important real-time challenges.

To use PREEMPT_RT, you will have to patch and build your kernel.  Steps would be:

1. Get kernel source code for your target system
2. Get PREEMPT_RT patch from **https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup**
3. Apply patch and install your own kernel

The PREEMPT_RT patch is available for kernel versions 2.6.22 up to 4.9.
See:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/